# Problems with existence of a solution for $ \mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla u - \nabla \cdot [D(u)\nabla u ] =0 \text{ in } \Omega, t>0$ if $D(u)=0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE

$$ \mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla u - \nabla \cdot [D(u)\nabla u ] =0 \text{ in } \Omega, t>0$$

with Dirichlet boundary condition $u=g(x,y)$ on $\partial \Omega$, $t>0$ and initial condition $u(0,(x,y))=u_0(x,y)$. $\mathbf{v}$ is a constant velocity field (over the domain and over time). It is stated that there are problems with the existence of a solution to this PDE if $D(u)=0$. My reasoning for this is that, if $\mathbf{v}$ is non-zero then grad $u$ has to be zero  which implies that the solution should be constant. But if $g(x,y)$ is non-constant then this will introduce a discontinuity at the boundary?

Is this reasoning correct or are there other reason why there can be problems with the existence of a solution if $D(u) = 0$?

Comment: Sorry, but _why_ does grad $u$ have to be zero if $\boldsymbol{v}$ is non-zero? It would seem that if $D(u) = 0$ then you are just solving a a first order transport problem. However, the first order transport problem may have problems with existence depending on the forms of both the characteristics and the boundary data $g$.

Comment: Yes you're right, what I said is wrong about $\mathbf{v}$ being zero. But what could be the problem with existence then?