# Confusion about existence of solution boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, finite-element-method

I have the following boundary value problem (for my applied finite elements course):

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
  \mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla u - \nabla \cdot \left[ D(u) \nabla u\right] = 0 & \mathrm{in}\, \Omega, \\
   u = g(x,y) &\mathrm{on}\,\partial\Omega. 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here $g(x,y)$ and $D(u)$ are given functions and the velocity field $\mathbf{v}$ is assumed to be given and constant over the domain. It is stated (without proof) that one can expect problems with the existence of a solution if $D(u)=0$. Therefore we take $D(u)$ to be nonzero. I do not see why this is the case. If $D(u)=0$, the PDE would be $ \mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla u = 0$. How do I know that this has no solution?

Comment: This question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097814/problems-with-existence-of-a-solution-for-mathbfv-cdot-nabla-u-nabla-c). I'm not sure what issue the person who stated this was thinking of, but it might be that if $D = 0$ then there is a reduction in the order of the PDE, whilst the boundary data is applicable for the higher order PDE and so the solutions to the lower order PDE $v \cdot \nabla u = 0$ might not satisfy the stated BCs for the $D \ne 0$ problem.

Comment: I believe mattos is right, take the simple example of $D=0$ and $v=(1, 1)$, then one has a transport equation with general solution $u(x,y) = u(x-y) $ which is not compatible with general boundary data $g(x,y) $